# how do i get the column name and or value?

Tags: t-sql

```
select 
t.slotmachinebk,
t.gamingdate, 
t.freeplaydownloaded, 
t.freeplayadjusted, 
t.freeplayplayed, 
t.freeplayabandoned, 
t.freeplaybalance 
from (select * from freeplay.egmfreeplay union all select * from Change.EgmFreePlay) t where not exists (select * from  testtable where

slotmachinebk = t.slotmachinebk and
auditdate = t.gamingdate and
freeplaydownloaded = t.freeplaydownloaded and
freeplayadjusted =  t.freeplayadjusted and
freeplayplayed = t.freeplayplayed and
freeplayabandoned = t.freeplayabandoned and 
freeplaybalance = t.freeplaybalance)
```

Well I have this tsql query that gives me the records that dont match between testtable and freeplay.egmfreeplay....but how do I modify this query to get the column name/value that dont match, column names being the columns used in subquery ANDs...

Comment: Please indent your code, it is pretty hard to read right now.

Comment: list the columns that join egmfreeplay to testtable

Answer (score 3):

You could put a bunch of 'CASE WHEN' statements in your SELECT query

```
CASE WHEN a.column1 <> b.column1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS column1_diff
```

Then you would see in your result set a '1' if that column was different for that record or a '0' if it wasn't different

**EDIT**

I attempted to refactor your query to something that will work.

```
SELECT      t.*,
            CASE WHEN t.slotmachinebk       <> z.slotmachinebk      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS slotmachinebk_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.gamingdate          <> z.gamingdate         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS gamingdate_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.freeplaydownloaded  <> z.freeplaydownloaded THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS freeplaydownloaded_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.freeplayadjusted    <> z.freeplayadjusted   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS freeplayadjusted_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.freeplayplayed      <> z.freeplayplayed     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS freeplayplayed_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.freeplayabandoned   <> z.freeplayabandoned  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS freeplayabandoned_diff,
            CASE WHEN t.freeplaybalance     <> z.freeplaybalance    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS freeplaybalance_diff,
FROM        testtable z
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT      * 
            FROM        freeplay.egmfreeplay 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT      * 
            FROM        Change.EgmFreePlay
            ) t
        ON  z.slotmachinebk         = t.slotmachinebk
        AND z.auditdate             = t.gamingdate
        AND z.freeplaydownloaded    = t.freeplaydownloaded
        AND z.freeplayadjusted      = t.freeplayadjusted
        AND z.freeplayplayed        = t.freeplayplayed
        AND z.freeplayabandoned     = t.freeplayabandoned
        AND z.freeplaybalance       = t.freeplaybalance
WHERE       t.id IS NOT NULL -- this will only select those in 'freeplay.egmfreeplay' and 'Change.EgmFreePlay' that are not in 'testtable', I am not sure if 'id' actually exists, but you want to use something that will never be NULL in those two tables
```

Comment: this won't work. the query has only 1 table in it: "t", the values from sub query in the where can not be used. You need to join in the other table then use the CASE WHEN. don't forget to account for NULLs

Comment: i tried it, but it gave me "multipart idenfier cannot be bound" error 
because I would be using the columns of the subquery (where all the ANDs are mentioned) to compare with the columns with the main query. Since the columsn in the subquery were used outside of the scope, it gives me the error...appreciate it though

Comment: you will have to rearrange your query to use joins instead of where clauses with 'IN' statements.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you want rows from each table where the records are different... if you have an identity column to match them on, you could join on that and then add your where clause to only pull records where those columns are different.

Comment: The resultset gives the data, one of which, or some of which or all which are faulty. So, instead of getting the all of them, I would like to have, for now, just the column name as value that is faulty.

If i figure this one out, then I would be looking for the actual value that the column possesses in compared tables.

Answer (score 0):

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

I'd don't know the key column names, but try this...

```
select 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.slotmachinebk           ,'')!=ISNULL(z.XXX                ,'') THEN 'slotmachinebk'       ELSE '' END AS slotmachinebk        --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.gamingdate         ,'')!=ISNULL(z.gamingdate         ,'') THEN 'gamingdate'          ELSE '' END AS gamingdate           --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.freeplaydownloaded ,'')!=ISNULL(z.freeplaydownloaded ,'') THEN 'freeplaydownloaded'  ELSE '' END AS freeplaydownloaded   --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.freeplayadjusted   ,'')!=ISNULL(z.freeplayadjusted   ,'') THEN 'freeplayadjusted'    ELSE '' END AS freeplayadjusted     --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.freeplayplayed     ,'')!=ISNULL(z.freeplayplayed     ,'') THEN 'freeplayplayed'      ELSE '' END AS freeplayplayed       --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.freeplayabandoned  ,'')!=ISNULL(z.freeplayabandoned  ,'') THEN 'freeplayabandoned'   ELSE '' END AS freeplayabandoned    --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
        ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(t.freeplaybalance    ,'')!=ISNULL(z.freeplaybalance    ,'') THEN 'freeplaybalance'     ELSE '' END AS freeplaybalance      --<<<<wrap all columns in this, make sure you make the ISNULL alternate value match the datatype of the column
    from (select * from freeplay.egmfreeplay union all select * from Change.EgmFreePlay) t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testtable z ON t.KEY=z.KEY  --<<<<<<<<key names???
    where not exists (select * from  testtable where
                             slotmachinebk = t.slotmachinebk and
                             auditdate = t.gamingdate and
                             freeplaydownloaded = t.freeplaydownloaded and
                             freeplayadjusted =  t.freeplayadjusted and
                             freeplayplayed = t.freeplayplayed and
                             freeplayabandoned = t.freeplayabandoned and 
                             freeplaybalance = t.freeplaybalance
                      )
```

Comment: the join, i think, is not possible because all columns in testtable are going to be compared with the same matching columns in freeplay.egmfreeplay table...If join is used, some records will be missed out...

Comment: ok let's put the question this way...the tsql query i posted earlier gives all records of freeplay.egmfreeplay+change.egmfreeplay that dont match with testable.  Now how can i use that tsql query to get the names of the actual column/s that dont match for a record?

Comment: how do you link the tables, if you can't they are all different. For example, to determine which cloths have changed on some people. The YESTERDAY table has a row for bill, joe, and sam, with cols hat, shirt, pants. The TODAY table has same rows & columns (just diff values for hat.shirt,pants). Compare yesterday.hat to today.hat for same person in each table (the join) does it make sense to compare joe's yesterday.hat to sam's today.hat? not to me, but is that what you are trying to do? I think you want to compare joe's yesterday.hat to joe's today.hat and sam's yesterday to sam's today, etc.

Comment: my apology..have not have lunch yet...so it s that crap hunger that making me write these weird senseless comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.slotmachinebk
       ,t.gamingdate
       , t.freeplaydownloaded
       , t.freeplayadjusted
       , t.freeplayplayed
       , t.freeplayabandoned
       , t.freeplaybalance 
from (select *  freeplay.egmfreeplay union all select * from Change.EgmFreePlay) t
left join testtable tt on 
      tt.slotmachinebk = t.slotmachinebk 
      and tt.auditdate = t.gamingdate 
      and tt.freeplaydownloaded = t.freeplaydownloaded 
      and freeplayadjusted =  t.freeplayadjusted 
      and tt.freeplayplayed = t.freeplayplayed 
      and tt.freeplayabandoned = t.freeplayabandoned 
      and tt.freeplaybalance = t.freeplaybalance
where tt.whateverTheHeckMyIdColumnIs is null
```

This should get you whatever is in your union that does not have an exact match in testtable. Of course you shouldn't not  use select * either, especially not in union (this query would break the first time someone changed a table structure in one but not both of the tables in the union). Learn to specify your columns. If you have no id on testtable, create one first or the change the where clause to a field that cannot be ever be null.